# Where is the proper place to manually set key/value pairs for POST data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

in Backbone?

I'm using POST to handle all CRUD operations and I need to know the proper place to set POST key/value pairs.

As an example how would you do this for a Collection fetch() request.

Please take note that I have over-ridden Backbone.Sync to always use POST.

Please understand I've done this for a reason and it will work fine as my server is setup this way for testing purposes.

Thanks.

Here is the over-ridden Sync FYI in Q/A format.

[Is it O.K. to re-write Backbone.sync by hard coding in values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014977/is-it-o-k-to-re-write-backbone-sync-by-hard-coding-in-values)

**Update**

It looks like it just needs to be set to the data property as an obeject literal or query string according to:

http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

Strange this info. was not in the jQuery ajax API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the manual

> jQuery.ajax options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection:
>   Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

you may also be interested in backbones emulate HTTP option

> If you want to work with a legacy web server that doesn't support
>   Backbone's default REST/HTTP approach, you may choose to turn on
>   Backbone.emulateHTTP. Setting this option will fake PUT, PATCH and
>   DELETE requests with a HTTP POST, setting the X-HTTP-Method-Override
>   header with the true method. If emulateJSON is also on, the true
>   method will be passed as an additional _method parameter.

http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP

Comment: I'm aware of the emulation methods and don't want to use them.  What I'm doing is similar though.

Comment: if its similar why not use the supported method ?

Comment: because it's similar not exact.  I don't want to use GET at the moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349949/force-backbone-fetch-to-always-use-post